# Docker backup restoration into non Docker environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am new to Docker, I have a very basic question, I am having docker container locally which is having my ready for production deployment work. I want to take complete docker container backup and restore in our cloud environment hosted by 3rd party where docker is not there and docker can not be installed.

Is it possible? if yes pl help me with steps

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of Docker is to `build and ship` your code through Docker images. An ideal way of doing this:-

1. Create a docker image locally and push it to docker-registry.
2. Install Docker on Cloud environment.
3. Pull your docker image from the registry and start the container.

As you mentioned, you can't install Docker on this, then write shell scripts to achieve this:-

1. Write a shell script which will install the same versions of tools and frameworks which you used in your Docker container.
2. Create an artefact - Depending on your application (Could be jar, tar, etc.) and push it to some artefactory.
3. Run the shell scripts in your Cloud environment.

But still, with this approach, it will take some time to replicate the whole setups.

I would highly suggest you go with the ideal way and it's really easy.

Answer (score 0):

If Docker isn't available in your production environment, then trying to develop and package exclusively in Docker isn't a good match.

There are a number of existing system-automation tools (Ansible, Chef, and Salt Stack come to mind as prominent options) that can be used to install software on systems.  If you have, for example, an Express/Node-based server application, it's a very routine use of these tools to make sure the right version of Node is installed on the server, copy (or update) the application code, and (re)start the application.  This is a very normal deployment path, and was fairly mature even before Docker existed.  I would look into this as a first choice.

In principle a Docker container is sort of like a chroot, with an isolated network namespace and several restrictions on what the container process is allowed to do.    There are several options (published ports, volume mounts) that don't quite map cleanly into a non-Docker environment; you'd have to manually maintain processes instead of being able to use higher-level `docker` or `docker-compose` commands.  I wouldn't attempt what you're describing without having a good understanding of what "being in a chroot" really means, and even then, this wouldn't be my preferred approach: either install Docker and use it, or keep Docker out of the picture entirely.

Since a Dockerfile mostly consists of `COPY`ing files and `RUN`ning shell commands, it's hopefully straightforward to translate your existing image construction into an Ansible playbook or Chef recipe that will work in this non-Docker environment.